# Dynamically create array from simple variable

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have this variable in php:

```
$log = "
- [ADD] Lorem Ipsum.
- [FIX] consetetur sadipscing elitr.
- [IMP] sed diam voluptua.";
```

I'm trying to create the following 2-D array like:

```
$logarray = array (
        array (
            "type" => "ADD",
            "description" => "Lorem Ipsum."
        ),
        array (
            "type" => "FIX",
            "description" => "consetetur sadipscing elitr."
        ),
        array (
            "type" => "IMP",
            "description" => "sed diam voluptua."
        )
);
```

I am thinking of using the function `explode()` but I do not know how in this case.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: regular expressions would be more convenient in this case

Comment: You're right, the expression has to be able to recognize the text inside the `[]` for the `type`

Comment: And the description as well `\[[^\]]+\]\s+[^\n]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by either using reg exp or completely using string functions by PHP.
Here is the code using reg exp:

```
$log = "
  [ADD] Lorem Ipsum.
- [FIX] consetetur sadipscing elitr.
- [IMP] sed diam voluptua.";
$log_parts = explode('-', trim($log));
$b = array_map("type_element", $log_parts);
print_r($b);

function type_element($log_part)
{
    preg_match("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $log_part, $element_type);
    return array( 
       'type' => $element_type[0], 
       'description' => preg_replace("/\[[^\]]*\]/", "", $log_part)
    );
}
```

In above code, at first, we made it an array by a fixed pattern '-'. Please notice that, the first line of string has no '-', its better to remove to make it usable for explode().

And then used a method to get the desired array from each string.